# How to get object or class from dropdown. After I would like use two fields inside class

Tags: flutter, drop-down-menu, dropdown

```
dynamic _selectArea = '0'; 

dropdown() {
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection("Areas")
                        .snapshots(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          List<DropdownMenuItem> areasItem = [];

          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            const CircularProgressIndicator();
          } else {
            final pastoLista = snapshot.data?.docs.reversed.toList();
            areasItem.add(
              DropdownMenuItem<Object>(
                value: '0',
                child: Text('What area come from ?',
                    style: TextStyle(color: lightColorScheme.secondary)),
              ),
            );

            for (var areas in pastoLista!) {
              areasItem.add(DropdownMenuItem<Object>(
                
                value: areas, // Here >
                child: Text(
                  areas["name"],
                  
                ),
              ));
            }
          }
          return DropdownButtonFormField(
            decoration:
                const InputDecoration(prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.fmd_good_rounded)),
            
            items: areasItem,
            onChanged: (areaValue) {
              setState(() {
                _selectArea = areaValue;
                print(_selectArea);
                
              });
            },
            value: _selectArea,
            validator: (valor) {
              return valor == '0' ? "Escolha um Areas" : null;
            },
           
            isExpanded: true,
          );
        });
  }
```

I have error for dropdown. The error occurs after choosen dropdown choice
I not want String value for _select value, I want selection from Class to use more fields to save on form fields

The objective is for me to use two fields from the object chosen in the dropdown

I've try DYNAMIC type on _select value of dropdown but don't work